# Difference between Pojo and HashMap in updateChildren

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

It's correct to say that "if I save a POJO with some value null in Firebase with updateChildren function it's the same thing that I have with the same POJO in setValue". I wan't delete anything. In this case must I use `HashMap`?

THE CODE

```
usrBuilder = new Users.Builder();
        usrBuilder.setUid(uid)
                .setFull_name(name.getText().toString())
                .setSex((rb_F.isChecked())?"F":"M")
                .setBirthDate(data_nascita.getText().toString())
                .setEmail(email.getText().toString())
                .setCity_live(citta.getText().toString());

usrUpdated = new Users(usrBuilder);
        firebaseUpdate.put("/Users/"+uid+"/", usrUpdated);

//POJO USERS
public Users(Builder builder){
        uid = builder.uid;
        email= builder.email;
        full_name= builder.full_name;
        sex = builder.sex;
        birth_date = builder.birth_date;
        city_live = builder.city_live;
        url_img_profile_large = builder.url_img_profile_large;
        url_img_profile_small = builder.url_img_profile_small;

    }
```

url_img_profile* are deleted.

Now I understand my problem because it sees null value.

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- Users
         |
         --- uid
                |
                --- name: "name"
                |
                --- sex: "F" 
                |
                --- email: "email@ame.it"
                |
                --- birth_date: "Jun 1, 2018" 
                |
                --- city: "Campobasso"
                |
                --- url_photo_small: "urlStorage" 
                |
                --- url_photo_large: "urlStorage"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `setValue()` method you are overriding the object at that particular location and when you are using `updateChildren()` method, you are updating the values of the children that exist at that particular location. So rememeber, you can automatically map the key/value pairs to a POJO that conforms to JavaBeans standards or you can access each key/value pair individually using a `Map`.

Assuming you have database structure that looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- items
         |
         --- itemIdOne
                |
                --- name: "ItemOne"
```

The simplest way to remove a record would be to user `removeValue()` directly on the reference:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.child("items").child(itemIdOne).removeValue();
```

Comment: In my case I use POJO with a User class. In the console I have an existing Users that have other data. I use updateChildren setting only name and email. When I see in Firebase console I have only name and email. The rest of data are deleted.

Comment: Yes and this is because you are using `setValue()` method. Please note, that in NoSQL database, every node represents a pair of key and value. With other words, every node is a `Map` and the case of Map, when using this method it replaces the old value with the new one. If you want to update or delete a single property just use a map and `updateChildren()` method.

Comment: My problem is that I use updateChildren and not setValue().

Comment: Please share your code and your database structure to see the issue more clearly.

Comment: Yes. The use of builder save null data to other nodes and it gives me wrong values. Thanks.

Comment: No, because it isn't what I wanted to know

Comment: Then please share your code and your database structure to see the issue more clearly.

Comment: I cannot see your database structure.